# Check if the string contains only english chars

Tags: java

I am a new Java developer,
I want to know how to check if the string contains only English letters or not.
I search the but I got answer in PHP. I have not tried anything because I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java regex for that:

```
if((!str.equals("")) 
            && (str != null) 
            && (str.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$"))) {
// Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try somthing like

```
char c = 'h';
if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
 //english letter
}
```